# Copy specific column data from one sheet to another depends on change in a cell data

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I would like to copy B2:D2 data from my sheet MW to TimeStampWork depends upon the change in sheet MW B2 value. On sheet TimeStampWork, I need to add them on Row + 1 when the code runs each time.

I am using below code. But the problem it is copying only B2 cell data, not B2:D2.
Please let me know how can I copy the range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set mw = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("MW")
Set ws = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("TimeStampWork")
 If Value <> mw.Range("B2").Value Then

ws.Range("B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = mw.Range("B2:D2").Value


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: change `ws.Range("B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = ...` to `ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1,3).Value = ...` (that should do the trick)

Comment: @DirkReichel:  Thanks. Its working